# Given $f(x)=x^2+ax+2b$ with $a\in [1.2,5]$ and $b\in [-0.8,1.5]$, what is the probability that $f(x)$ has two real roots?

Tags: probability, contest-math, roots, quadratics

A friend and me tried to solve this problem and we took two different approachs:

while both considered the probability as a quotient between areas, he used an auxiliary function
$$g(a)=\frac{a^2}{8}$$ and computed the following area:
[Approach 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEGDW.png), getting probability as shadowed area over rectangle area $P\approx 0.801$.

On the other hand I took the two intervals $a^2\equiv x\in [1.2^2,5^2]$ and $8b\equiv y\in 8\cdot[-0.8,1.5]$ obtaining the following area [Approach 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92OfK.png) and computating the probability as area below $y=x$ over rectangle area $P\approx 0.87$.

So, I have been trying to understand which one of the approachs is wrong and why but I have failed so I am here.

EDIT:
also, is there any point $(x\equiv a^2,y\equiv 8b)$ in the region where $x>y$ of the approach 2 that return a quadratic polynomial without two real roots?

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ independent and uniformly distributed on their respective intervals? Then $a^2$ and $b^2$ are no longer uniform distributed, so you can't calculate anymore the probability as the ratio of the areas.

Comment: @Momo yes, a and b are independent and uniformly distributed on their respective interval as assumption, why can not you do that? thanks

Comment: Because "areas ratio" method works only for uniformly distributed.

Comment: @Momo my question is why $a^2$ is not uniform distributed, thanks

Comment: $P(a^2\le x)=P(a\le\sqrt{x})=F_a(\sqrt{x})$, so $f_{a^2}(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}f_a(\sqrt{x})=\frac{1}{7.6\sqrt{x}}$ for $1.2^2<x<5^2$, which is obviously not constant.

Comment: @Momo well thanks, can you provide me some reading about? thanks again

Comment: Any introductory probability course, a summary is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Functions_of_random_variables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with Approach 2 is the non-linearity of your variable transformation.  The problem this creates is that the area of the triangle in the upper-left corner of the graph, which represents the complementary probability, is made disproportionately small , so a simple subtraction of that triangular area leads to an over-estimate of the probability sought.

[image]

Let's carry out the integration for "Approach 1" first in order to compare it against what must be done for the other Approach.  We will compute the area "above" the parabola $ \ b \ = \ \frac{a^2}{8} \ \ , $ in order to determine the complement to the probability for two real zeroes.  The total area of the "population space" rectangle is $ \ \mathbf{A} \ = \ ( \ 5 - 1.2 \ )·( \ 1.5 - [-0.8] \ ) \ = \ 8.74 \ \ . $  The area above the parabolic arc is found from the double integral
$$ \mathcal{A} \ \ = \ \ \int_{1.2}^{\sqrt{12}} \int_{a^2/8}^{1.5} \ \ db \ \ da \ \ = \ \ \int_{1.2}^{\sqrt{12}} \int_{a^2/8}^{1.5} \ \ db \ \ da \ \ = \ \ \int_{1.2}^{\sqrt{12}} \ 1.5 \ - \ \frac{a^2}{8} \ \ \ da $$ $$ = \ \  \left. \left( \ 1.5·a \ - \ \frac{a^3}{24} \ \right)\right|_{1.2}^{\sqrt{12}} \ \ \approx \ \ 1.736 \ \ . $$
[The upper limit on the integral in $ \ a \ $ is found from $ \ \frac{a^2}{8} \ = \ 1.5 \ \ .  $ ]  We thereby calculate the probability that the given quadratic polynomial has two real zeroes in the specified "coefficient region" as
$$ 1 \ - \ \frac{\mathcal{A}}{\mathbf{A}} \ \ \approx \ \ 1 \ - \ \frac{1.736}{8.74} \ \ = \ \ 0.801 \ \ . $$

[image]

For the variable substitution $ \ u \ = \ a^2 \ \ , \ \ v \ = \ 8b \ \ , $ we obtain the rectangle above; the parabolic arc becomes $ \ b \ = \ \frac{a^2}{8} \ \rightarrow \ v \ = \ u \ \ . $  We will want to compute the complementary probability by finding the area of the triangle above that line and within the rectangle.  This requires us to transform the *differentials* in the integral as well, which we achieve by the use of the Jacobian
$$ \mathfrak{J} \ \ = \ \ \left[\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial a} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial b} \\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial a} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial b} \end{array} \right] \ \ = \ \ \left[\begin{array}{cc}
2a & 0 \\
0 & 8 \end{array} \right] \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ | \ \mathfrak{J} \ | \ \ = \ \ 16a \ \rightarrow \ 16·\sqrt{u} \ \  .  $$

Under this transformation, even the area of the rectangle must be integrated and is *not* simply the product of its length and width.  We now calculate
$$ \mathbf{A'} \ \ = \ \ \int_{1.2^2}^{5^2} \int_{8·(-0.8)}^{8·1.5} \ \ \frac{1}{| \ \mathfrak{J} \ |} \ \ dv \ \ du \ \ = \ \ \int_{1.44}^{25} \int_{-6.4}^{12} \ \ \frac{1}{16·\sqrt{u}} \ \  dv \ \ du $$ $$ = \ \ \frac{1}{16} \ \int_{1.44}^{25} \ \left. \frac{v}{\sqrt{u}} \right|_{-6.4}^{12} \ \ \ du \ \ = \ \ \frac{18.4}{16} \ \int_{1.44}^{25} \   \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}   \ \ \ du \ \ = \ \ \frac{18.4}{16} \ · \ 2  ·    \sqrt{u}|_{1.44}^{25} \ \ = \ \ 8.74 \ \ . $$
So we find the same area for the "transformed" rectangle as we did with the original coordinates.  The area of the transformed complementary region is

$$ \mathcal{A'} \ \ = \ \ \int_{1.2^2}^{\sqrt{12}^2} \int_{u}^{8·1.5} \ \ \frac{1}{16·\sqrt{u}} \ \  dv \ \ du \ = \ \ \frac{1}{16} \ \int_{1.44}^{12} \ \left. \frac{v}{\sqrt{u}} \right|_{u}^{12} \ \ \ du $$ $$ = \ \ \frac{1}{16} \ \int_{1.44}^{12} \  \left( \ \frac{12}{\sqrt{u}} \ - \ \sqrt{u} \ \right)   \ \ du \ \  = \ \  \frac{1}{16} \ \left. \left( \ 12·2·\sqrt{u} \ - \ \frac{2}{3}·u^{3/2} \ \right)\right|_{1.44}^{12} \ \ \approx \ \ 1.736 \ \ . $$

We find the area of the transformed region to be the same as that of the original one, giving us the probability we wished to determine as
$$ 1 \ - \ \frac{\mathcal{A'}}{\mathbf{A'}} \ \ = \ \ 1 \ - \ \frac{\mathcal{A}}{\mathbf{A}} \ \ \approx  \ \ 0.801 \ \ . $$

The discrepancy in Approach 2 is due to the omission of  the non-linear effect of the chosen variable transformation.  (Leaving out the Jacobian is a not uncommon error in such calculations.)

Answer (score 0):

Counting roots of the equation $Ax^2 + Bx + C = 0$ depends on the sign of the determinant $B^2-4AC$:

- There are two real roots if and only if $B^2-4AC > 0$

For your problem, where $A=1$, $B=a$, and $C=2b$, this translates into:

- There are two real roots if and only if $a^2 - 8b > 0$, equivalently
  $$b < \frac{a^2}{8}
  $$

So the region in Approach 1 is indeed the correct region to consider. And as you said in the comments, $a$ and $b$ are independent and uniformly distributed, so the probability measure on that rectangle is indeed proportional to probability (you just have to divide out by the total area $(5 - 1.2) \times (1.5-(-.8))$).

I would like to be able to critique Approach 2, however the axes are not labelled and no region is shaded in, so it's hard to know what to say. Even assuming the vertical axis is $y$ and the horizontal axis is $x$ as you seem to be hinting in your post, I'm not sure what relation the equation $y=x$ has to the equation $x^2 + ax + 2b$.

Comment: below $y=x$, $x$ is such that $x>y$

Comment: The inequality $x>y$ does not have anything to do with counting the number of zeros of the equation $x^2 + ax + 2b=0$.

Comment: but as $a^2$ is defined to be $x$ and analogous with $8b$ and $y$, I thought to consider where is $a^2>8b$.

Comment: In your problem, the variable $x$  plays the role of the independent variable of the function $f(x) = x^2 + ax + 2b$. You are not free to change the role of $x$ and set it equal to $x=a^2$. Notice that in picture you posted for Approach 1, after the inequality $a^2-8b>0$ is solved for $b$ to get the inequality $b < \frac{a^2}{8}$, the horizontal axis is labelled $a$ and the vertical axis is labelled $b$. So in that picture you can, if you like, think of $a$ as the independent variable and $b$ the dependent variable. But you should not mix those roles up with the $x$ in the original function!

Comment: does that have to do with $a^2$ not being uniform distributed? If so I just need to understand why it is not.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have two real roots, we require that $a^2-8b>0,$ where the ordered pair $\langle a,b\rangle$ is taken from some distribution on $\left[\frac65,5\right]\times\left[-\frac45,\frac32\right].$ I assume herein that this distribution is assumed to be uniform.

Put another way, since $a^2$ is necessarily positive, we require that $b<\frac18a^2,$ given $a,b$ in the selected area.

Geometrically, this amounts to the area under the curve $y=\frac18 x^2,$ under the line $y=\frac32,$ and over the line $y=-\frac45$ within the $x$-interval $\left[\frac65,5\right].$

After drawing the graphs of these curves, it's clear that $\frac18x^2>-\frac45$ for all $x.$ Moreover, $\frac18x^2=\frac32$ exactly when $x=\sqrt{12}$ for $x\in\left[\frac65,5\right].$ Hence, we're looking at the area between $y=\frac18 x^2$ and $y=-\frac45$ in the interval $\left[\frac65,\sqrt{12}\right],$ and between $y=\frac32$ and $y=-\frac45$ in the interval $\left[\sqrt{12},5\right].$

Put another way, we need to evaluate $$\int_{\frac65}^{\sqrt{12}}\left(\frac18x^2+\frac45\right)\,dx+\int_{\sqrt{12}}^5\left(\frac32+\frac45\right)\,dx$$ for the answer.

Comment: That is the approach 1, I am trying to understand (quantitative if possible) why approach 2 is wrong, thanks for answering

Comment: As far as I can tell, it's simply because you used a straight line, rather than a parabola, but it's hard to tell with the lack of labels.

Comment: $x\equiv a^2$ horizontal axis and $y\equiv 8b$ vertical one.

Comment: The black line in the picture suggests that something is wrong. It should be a portion of a parabola (opening up)--namely, $y=\frac18x^2.$

Comment: in that approach I made a kind of variable change $a^2\rightarrow x$ and $8b\rightarrow y$ so below $y=x$ we have $x>y$ and hence $a^2>8b$

Comment: Ah! The issue then is that both of your variables are *independent*, so you **can't** make that change of variables.

Comment: Then because $a$ and $b$ are independent I can't relate them in order to solve the task, right? But isn't approach 1 based on that relation? Kind of confusing

Comment: Not at all. Approach 1 starts with the assumption of independence and uniform distribution. Next, it restricts to that proportion of the ordered pairs $\langle a,b\rangle$ that fit the specific restrictions.